# I made one shoot of it off the house

Tags: meaning-in-context, informal-language

(From *'The Wrecker'* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, Chapter XII, published 1892)

> . . . And with that he smiled like a man recalling something. “Look here, that brings a yarn in my head,” he resumed; “and for the sake of the joke, I'll give myself away. It was in 1874, I shipped mate in the British ship *Maria*, from 'Frisco for Melbourne. She was the queerest craft in some ways that ever I was aboard of. The food was a caution; there was nothing fit to put your lips to—but the lime-juice, which was from the end bin no doubt; it used to make me sick to see the men's dinners, and sorry to see my own. The old man was good enough, I guess; Green was his name—a mild, fatherly old galoot. But the hands were the lowest gang I ever handled; and whenever I tried to knock a little spirit into them, the old man took their part! It was Gilbert and Sullivan on the high seas; but you bet I wouldn't let any man dictate to me. 'You give me your orders, Captain Green,' I said, 'and you'll find I'll carry them out; that's all you've got to say. You'll find I do my duty,' I said; 'how I do it is my lookout; and there's no man born that's going to give me lessons.' Well, there was plenty dirt on board that *Maria* first and last. Of course, the old man put my back up, and, of course, he put up the crew's; and I had to regular fight my way through every watch. The men got to hate me, so's I would hear them grit their teeth when I came up. At last, one day, I saw a big hulking beast of a Dutchman booting the ship's boy. **I made one shoot of it off the house** and laid that Dutchman out. Up he came, and I laid him out again. 'Now,' I said, 'if there's a kick left in you, just mention it, and I'll stamp your ribs in like a packing-case.' He thought better of it, and never let on; lay there as mild as a deacon at a funeral; and they took him below to reflect on his native Dutchland.

What does *I made one shoot **of it** off the house* mean in this context; especially, the words *of it* trouble me - what do they mean there?

Comment: To [shoot](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shoot) can mean "to move in a particular direction very quickly and directly" or "to throw, hit, or kick a ball or other object toward a goal", perhaps "shoot a punch". I don't know about "off the house" but I guess the whole phrase to mean that he made an instant decision  to hit the man.

Comment: I suspect *off the house* is meant locative - the whole thing takes place on a schooner deck and *house* is the cabin or the small pilothouse of the schooner - but it's just a guess.

Comment: Perhaps "I made one shoot of it" means "I did it in a single attempt".

Comment: Yes, I agree. It could mean *I take a leap* or *I give a jerk*, but **a** should be stressed there, I suppose, that is **of it** could be an intensifier there in my opinion, right?

Comment: I think "of it" means "of the job".

Comment: Whereof one cannot speak, thereof one must be silent. What you don't know, you should keep quiet :)

Comment: It's not an intensifier.

Comment: "I made one shoot of it off the house" could mean "covered the distance between us with a single leap from the pilot house" and "of it" would refer to the distance that needed to be traversed in order to be within striking distance of the Dutchman.  Compare: "There was a lot of work to be done hauling those stones to the barn, but I made a single go **of it** and was done by dinnertime."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "*make one shoot of something*" is a more literary way of saying *do something in a single action*. The more modern version of this is *do something in one shot/one go*.

So in this context, it means he *did whatever "it" is in one attempt*.

I believe "house" was once an informal word for "head". It's clear from the context that he beat the other man, so I'm guessing the whole phrase means roughly:

> ... knocked the Dutchman down with a single punch to the head